# Parkour - Tricking - Free-running in Tokyo?

Tags: japan, tokyo

I'm looking to connect with people who do parkour, tricking or free-running in the Tokyo area. Does anyone happen to know of any facebook groups or other contact info to do so (Japanese or English)?

Comment: is this how you catch your plane if you are late :) ?

Comment: @chx see for yourself https://youtu.be/79k1ajjPZAI?t=2m25s

Answer (score 5):

There's a Tokyo parkour meetup group here:

http://www.meetup.com/Tokyo-Tricking/

Answer (score 3):

My precedent message was deleted, thx to the mod, so I will repost: 
link I found on a PK community in Tokyo:  https://www.facebook.com/groups/546722498757646/ & they have a website too.

There is also a Parkour club but it's quit expensive:  http://tokyoparkouracademy.jimdo.com.

Comment: Why would the mod delete it... -_-